# Override Sylius state machine

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'm trying to customize `sylius_order` state machine by adding a `validated` status and `validate` transition. 
This transition is a connection between the `new` and `validated` statuses.
When debuging my app using `debug:winzou:state-machine sylius_order` I see the right graph but when in code I try to use `$stateMachine->getPossibleTransitions()` on a state machine with `new` status I only see the `cancel` and `fulfill` transitions.

Does someone know the solution about this ? Thanks

Comment: can you share state machine config and current entity state?

Comment: Actually I managed to find the solution. I was using a guard callback instead of before/after one and it was causing the issue. 
Sorry you lost your time on this question